# Could you give me some explain about how to calculate a partial derivative？

Tags: calculus

I'm reading an article about machine learning theory, there are has a step as below to calculate partial derivative:

```
∂(w5 * h1 + w6 * h2 + b3) / ∂h1 = w5 * f′(w5 * h1 + w6 * h2 + b3)
```

As I understand the caclulation method of partial derivative, the result of ∂(w5 * h1 + w6 * h2 + b3) / ∂h1 should be **w5**, should not be **w5 * f′(w5 * h1 + w6 * h2 + b3)**, I'm very confused this step, could you tell me some explain? Thank you.

Comment: 1) What you understand is "derivative", not "partial derivative" - you'd only get a plain `w5` if everything except `h1` was a constant. 2) Can't say more without more context (e.g. what article). 3) Maths, not programming, thus probably off-topic here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe there is a typo in the formula that you are reading.

```
∂f(w5 * h1 + w6 * h2 + b3) / ∂h1 = w5 * f′(w5 * h1 + w6 * h2 + b3)
```

I believe there should be an f on the LHS of the equation, after which, [chain rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule) is being applied.

If `f` is absent, then you are right.

Comment: Yes, I read the article again, you are right, I didn't notice the f on the LHS of the equation, thank you very much.